# How do I change the iPython default editor from Notepad to VIM?

Tags: vim, ipython

How do I change iPython's default editor for .py files from Notepad to VIM?  I'm currently running iPython on Windows 10.

Ipython documentation states (https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html)

*"You can also control the editor by setting TerminalInteractiveShell.editor in ipython_config.py."*

In the file ipython_config.py, the following lines seem to be the relevant lines that need to be modified:

```
#Set the editor used by iPython (default to $EDITOR/vi/notepad)
#c.TerminalINteractiveShell.editor = 'mate -w'
```

What should I change to make vim the default?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using windows but i think that fix like this:

```
ipython --TerminalInteractiveShell.editor=c:/usr/bin/vim/gvim.exe
```

Check [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/IPython/comments/3xpwa2/how_can_i_set_default_editor_in_windows/) link.